# How to Handle Large Sets of Data in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, arrays, performance

I'm currently creating a calculator for a client that has a set of options which all feed into an algorithm which throws out a few figures. The algorithm is coded in PHP and jQuery feeds in the selected options through it's ajax method.

It's better to show than tell so here it is:

http://clients.benpalmer.me/the-eco-experts/solar-calulator/

The calculator currently works out the new figures once an option is selected (but not during). Basically, I'm wanting if possible to use real time calculations so when you slide a percentage slider for example - the figures update as you're sliding (not after).

This is set up with a mysql database which has 8760 rows of data and each row is needed to figure the final figures. As you can probably imagine - this isn't particularly fast.

I'm trying to work out a faster method of figuring this out (I'm not sure if there actually is a faster method).

So far I've thought about putting all of this data in to an array instead on the off-chance that it would be faster. After testing this out - it seems to work at the same sort of speed (probably a bit slower). I've also tried to use the SplFixedArray class in PHP but again, with so much data - there is no discernible improvement in performance.

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find any other method and I suspect that I'm fighting a losing battle with this one but any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I was able to calculate the figures that I needed on the fly with PHP. It involved  a HUGE loop but it's helped drastically with the speed.

Answer (score 1):

You should try [Redis](http://redis.io)(Predis it's the name for PHP library) to store your arrays (basically, relational database is not a good choice here, you should stick with NoSQL engines). I suggest using Hashmaps but please keep in mind that storing more than 1000 keys will slow down the performance of it. A great solution for that problem has been described by Instagram developers [on their blog](http://instagram-engineering.tumblr.com/post/12202313862/storing-hundreds-of-millions-of-simple-key-value-pairs), I think that this might be useful for you in this specific case.